# Convert uint8_t to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, character-encoding, nsstring

Just started learning objective-c and was trying to convert a byte array into UTF8 NSString but have been getting nil/null.
Here is the abbreviated code sample.

```
enum {
  TMessageType_CALL = 1,
  TMessageType_REPLY = 2,
  TMessageType_EXCEPTION = 3,
  TMessageType_ONEWAY = 4
};

int32_t VERSION_1 = 0x80010000;

int value = VERSION_1 | TMessageType_CALL;
uint8_t buff[4];
buff[0] = 0xFF & (value >> 24);
buff[1] = 0xFF & (value >> 16);
buff[2] = 0xFF & (value >> 8);
buff[3] = 0xFF & value;

  //Convert buff to NSString with offset =0, length =4
```

I tried the following.

```
NSString *t = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buff length:4 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *t1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)buff];
```

But both `t` and `t1` return `nil`.
What is the right API to convert it correctly?
This conversion needs to be generic across WriteI32() writeI64(), writeString(), writeDouble(). Here is the code for the rest.

```
- (void) writeI16: (short) value
{
  uint8_t buff[2];
  buff[0] = 0xff & (value >> 8);
  buff[1] = 0xff & value;
  [mTransport write: buff offset: 0 length: 2];
}


- (void) writeI64: (int64_t) value
{
  uint8_t buff[8];
  buff[0] = 0xFF & (value >> 56);
  buff[1] = 0xFF & (value >> 48);
  buff[2] = 0xFF & (value >> 40);
  buff[3] = 0xFF & (value >> 32);
  buff[4] = 0xFF & (value >> 24);
  buff[5] = 0xFF & (value >> 16);
  buff[6] = 0xFF & (value >> 8);
  buff[7] = 0xFF & value;
  [mTransport write: buff offset: 0 length: 8];
}

- (void) writeDouble: (double) value
{
  // spit out IEEE 754 bits - FIXME - will this get us in trouble on
  // PowerPC?
  [self writeI64: *((int64_t *) &value)];
}


- (void) writeString: (NSString *) value
{
  if (value != nil) {
    const char * utf8Bytes = [value UTF8String];
    size_t length = strlen(utf8Bytes);
    [self writeI32: length];
    [mTransport write: (uint8_t *) utf8Bytes offset: 0 length: length];
  } else {
    // instead of crashing when we get null, let's write out a zero
    // length string
    [self writeI32: 0];
  }
}
```

Comment: The 4 bytes in `buf` do not represent a valid UTF-8 string. That is why you get `nil`. What result do you actually want? Show what the desired string should look like.

Comment: I understand. My goal is to create a MD5 out this binary data and then transmit it using HTTP. The above snippet has the version for writing I32, I have other variations too e.g writeString() writeI64() etc. I updated the code above.

Comment: You can't create a string out of the raw bytes `0x80`, `0x01`, `0x00`, `0x01` which is what the posted code is trying to do. Why do you want to create a string at all? Stick with working with the byte data or `NSData`.

Comment: OK, based on the updated code in the question, the need to create a string from the bytes is even less clear.

Comment: The MD5 is then compared with Java(server) generated MD5 to check for consistency.

Comment: I'll second what rmaddy said: NSString is for Unicode strings and *cannot* hold arbitrary binary data. It does not work and makes no sense, period. You should use NS(Mutable)Data instead.

Comment: This doesn't look like a UTF-8 string. Are you sure it's valid UTF-8?

Comment: Got it. I will ditch attempting to convert to NSString and rather generate MD5 from NSData directly. Using this.  '- (NSString*)MD5
{
  // Create byte array of unsigned chars
  unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
 
  // Create 16 byte MD5 hash value, store in buffer
  CC_MD5(self.bytes, self.length, md5Buffer);
 
  // Convert unsigned char buffer to NSString of hex values
  NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
  for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) 
    [output appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];
 
  return output;
}'

Answer (score 5):

`buff` is an array of `unsigned char`s, so you could use this:

```
NSString *t = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", buff];
```

As an alternative, you can get each character explicitly:

```
NSMutableString *t = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:4];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    [t appendFormat:@"%c", buff[i]];
NSLog(@"%@", t);
```

The first option does a conversion to a valid string. The second option gives you each character, regardless of any terminating characters ('\0').

I'm not sure what useful information this will give you, but there you have it.

Comment: No, these are not good solutions in this case. The buffer has a value of `0` in it so that will mess up the strings. Plus the 1st byte is `0x80` which isn't a valid character.

Comment: Mine is  @"\x02\x06\x01\x01\xe4\x84\x03" i don't know why it adds \x before every character.